# External HD stops working while transferring files

Tags: external-hard-drive, hard-drive-failure

I was moving some files into my external HD (WD Elements 4TB) when it suddenly stopped working, on the copy window i had a message saying that the destination was not available. When i touched the HD case it was pretty hot (not burning hot, but still hot for a hard drive) even though my room was quite cold and it was is a place where air can flow.
When i disconnect and reconnect it starts spinning but then i hear a series of clicking sounds, twice, then it stops and the light stays on. Windows does not recognize the device anymore (i receive a message saying that the USB device malfunctioned and Windows did not recognize it)

The HD was quite new and i had barely used it at this point so it kinda surprised me.
My questions are:

1. What might've happened to break an HD this way? Is it possible it broke because of overheating?
2. What can i do? I had already a broken HD in the past which i sent to a data recover company and it was succesfully recovered but it's quite expensive and i'd rather keep it as last resource, shall i send it for assistance (that is, if there's a chance to just repair it) or can i try something myself?

UPDATE: On the Windows Device manager properties for the HD (it's set as Unknown usb device) i have this error:

**Windows has stopped this device because it has reported problems. (Code 43)**

**The USB set address request failed.**

UPDATE #2 :

Using dmesg from an Ubuntu Live i have these messages regarding the HD:

```
[  918.651865] usb 2-5: new SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[  918.668550] usb 2-5: New USB device found, idVendor=1058, idProduct=107c
[  918.668553] usb 2-5: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
[  918.668554] usb 2-5: Product: Elements 107C
[  918.668555] usb 2-5: Manufacturer: Western Digital
[  918.668557] usb 2-5: SerialNumber: 574343344537564858334152
[  918.918200] usb-storage 2-5:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[  918.918253] scsi host6: usb-storage 2-5:1.0
[  918.918543] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[  919.019933] usbcore: registered new interface driver uas
[  919.917222] scsi 6:0:0:0: Direct-Access     WD       Elements 107C    1065 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[  919.917676] sd 6:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
[  919.918466] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Spinning up disk...
[  920.921786] ...........ready
[  930.970508] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] 976746240 4096-byte logical blocks: (3.90 TB/3.63 TiB)
[  930.970741] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
[  930.970743] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 53 00 10 08
[  930.970975] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] No Caching mode page found
[  930.970977] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  930.971274] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] 976746240 4096-byte logical blocks: (3.90 TB/3.63 TiB)
[  966.663478] usb 2-5: Disable of device-initiated U1 failed.
[  971.667647] usb 2-5: Disable of device-initiated U2 failed.
[  977.056036] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Command completion event does not match command
[  977.056053] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[  982.276406] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[  982.480572] usb 2-5: device not accepting address 2, error -62
[  982.537144] usb 2-5: USB disconnect, device number 2
[  982.544573] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[  982.544576] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00
[  982.544578] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 0
[  982.544581] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc, logical block 0, async page read
[  982.544602] ldm_validate_partition_table(): Disk read failed.
[  982.544614] Dev sdc: unable to read RDB block 0
[  982.544629]  sdc: unable to read partition table
[  982.544785] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[  982.544788] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Sense not available.
[  982.544837] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI disk
```

Comment: Have you tried connecting the HD to a different computer, or even to different USB ports?

Comment: Yes, i have tried both different computer (both with Windows 10, for what it matters) and ports, didn't work

Answer (score 2):

1. Could've been heat, movement, power, manufacturing defect, anything, nothing?
2. I'd return it to the store and get a refund or exchanged at least, trying at the manufacturer as a 2nd choice.

If you don't have a backup copy of the data (and you *really should* having experienced this once already) and want to try recovery yourself, you could try:

- Let the drive get cold (maybe even in a fridge/freezer) then try connecting it again & *quickly* copy off data. Keeping a fan or cooling pad near it shouldn't hurt.
- If it spins up but won't connect properly, try a lower level recovery program like testdisk/photorec or gddrescue (gnu ddrescue).
- See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery for more info on recovery & linux (Ubuntu but applicable to most)

Comment: Funny thing is that this was supposed to be the backup copy HD. I have most (but not all) of the data still with me. I'm gona try some things and see what happens (i'll avoid the freezer one, i had heard of it but i don't trust it...also i don't think i can "quickly" copy 3TB of data)

Comment: I have updated my answer with additional info, maybe it could help find the culprit

Comment: Another idea, maybe it's not getting enough quality power, try a (different) external power supply? Or possibly removing the drive from the external enclosure *could possibly maybe* help, but could void the warranty too, and some drives are "translated" strangely through the enclosure too, so may not read identically either.

Answer (score 1):

> When i disconnect it and reconnect it starts spinning but then i hear a series of clicking sounds, twice.

This indeed seems to be the [click of death](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Click_of_death), and yes, it means your disk has failed. I don't think the temperature is the reason of the failure, as external hard disks often get quite hot, particularly [Western Digital](https://www.google.com/search?channel=fs&q=western%20digital%20very%20hot&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=KgKFVuefBZGDaIyRuqgD) hard disks.

If the HD is new, hopefully it will be covered by the warranty, which allows you to get a new one, but recovering the data is a quite more difficult task.

As per the [Western Digital official site](http://support.wdc.com/warranty/rmapacking.asp?custtype=end), they won't do any information recovery task, though:

> Western Digital shall have no liability with respect to (a) data lost, regardless of the cause, (b) data recovery services, or (c) data contained in any Product placed in Western Digitals' possession. Western Digital is not liable for and has no obligation to pay for any cost associated with data recovery.

Personally I have a similar experience with several WD disks, so finally I decided to buy a different benchmark.

Comment: It doesn't sound like the click of death to me, at least it's not like the ones i heard from youtube and wikipedia, these are click...click...clik...click. The one from my device one is more like <spins> ClickClickClickClickClick............ClickClickClickClick...Click <stops spinning>

Comment: There are several types as far as I know, the ones you describe (only at the beggining and then like *nothing*) also might be a sign of broken disk. The most reliable test is plugging the disk to several computers (if it's a linux-based one and it recognizes the HD, it might also tell you the exact problem).

Comment: Click of death has changed over the years, your hard drive has failed.

Comment: i have added dmesg messages from an Ubuntu Live to my question. It does not recognize the HD though

Comment: @Moab i'd like to know (if possible) why and how it failed

Comment: The `hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT` message is one that I've seen many times with failed disks, so I think it's a confirmation that it's dead. About the reasons, could be anything: power surges, heat, faulty on manufacturing...

Comment: What does the rest of the messages mean?

Comment: In short, that it cannot read the disk. `Buffer I/O error on dev sdc, logical block 0, async page read` this particularly says it cannot even read the first block, so the result is the next line: `sdc: unable to read partition table`. Dead.

Comment: `gddrescue` wouldn't be stopped by an unreadable partition table, if *any* sectors are readable it should try... that's  if anything can be read at all

Comment: @valepu a million possible reasons, besides how would any of us here know what caused your hard drive to fail, or why.